# Convertir Columna EDAD de tipo object a INT

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estoy trabajando en Jupyter, al leer un archivo `.CSV` con varias columnas, de las cuales necesito transformar la columna `"EDAD"` a `INT` para poder realizar algoritmos de machine learning. El problema es que como pueden observar los datos varían entre `'78','0.666','70-70','0.5','44000','50.0','10+','5 months'`.

Se me ocurre otra solución en la cual eliminar todos los datos que no tengan este formato de edad `"xx"` puesto que el *dataset* tiene mas de 3 millones de registros, espero me puedan ayudar con las dos dudas y poder solucionar este problema

Dejare el error que me dio el jupyter igualmente:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'
```

¿Cómo puedo convertir columnas a números enteros?

[image: Los distintos datos de la columna EDAD]

Comment: A mi todavía no me queda claro cuales son las "dos dudas". ¿Qué código te produce ese error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero necesito una función que retorne el valor entero de cualquier string conteniendo un valor numérico, ya sea entero o flotante.

La función `to_int` recibe un string y trata de convertirlo usando `float` (para casos como 40.5) y luego `int`. Si parámetro recibido no es convertible, se genera una excepción y se retorna un string vacio.

```
def to_int(val):
    """ Reconoce valores numericos y los transforma a enteros.
    """
    try:
        value = int(float(val))
    except ValueError:
        value = ""
    return value
```

Ahora sólo resta aplicar esa función a cada elemento de la columna. Para esos usamos `map`, que aplica la función indicada a todos los elementos del dataframe/columna/fila que indiques:

```
df["Edad"] = df["Edad"].map(to_int)
```

El proceso completo se ejemplifica aqui:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def to_int(val):
    """ Reconoce valores numericos y los transforma a enteros.
    """
    try:
        value = int(float(val))
    except ValueError:
        value = ""
    return value

values = [np.NaN, "10", "10-20", "6 weeks", "40.5"]
df =pd.DataFrame(values, columns=["Edad"])

print(df)
df["Edad"] = df["Edad"].map(to_int)
print(df)
```

produce:

```
      Edad
0      NaN
1       10
2    10-20
3  6 weeks
4     40.5
  Edad
0     
1   10
2     
3     
4   40
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente deberías limpiar los datos que no siguen el formato de edad.

Luego de la limpieza, proba el siguiente código:

```
>>> df['EDAD'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

Pasas primero a string y luego a entero.

También borra los valores NaN.

Comment: Ya hice eso y da error porque no soporta los formatos :C, gracias por el consejo y los datos están sin valores nulos y "Seguramente deberías limpiar los datos que no siguen el formato de edad." y como hago eso elimino todos los valores por su formato correspondiente pero no me cruje la mente como hacer el codigo